# Feeding fish in tank with overflow

Tags: fish, aquarium, feeding, saltwater, clownfish

I am setting up my first saltwater aquarium and yesterday once the tank was finally set I added two clown fish and a star fish. How ever I quickly realized that the food reaches the overflow within seconds. I reduced the flow of the tank, not sure if this is ok. The food stays there a little longer but the fish don't seem to want to go to the top. The prefer the food that sinks, which isn't much as I'm using [Marine Flakes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0043TAUAE). Any ideas how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a practice, and to train your fish to know when food is going to be dropped, you should turn off the filter, skimmer, and all equipment which makes noise or bubbles, or any kind of water activity. Turning off wave makers while feeding fish, is not advised if you have corals (just my opinion). Then feed the fish by dropping the food into the water. After a while, when the fish are no longer interested in the food, start up all the equipment again.

I myself do such a shutdown, and then give 2 soft knocks on the tank hood, and after a while, the fish get used to the signals and come up for food.

If your fish do not come up for food, and you feed them flakes which float, then the food might be incompatible with your fish type. Buy slow sinking pellets or flakes or wafers which your fish might enjoy more. Also, be sure to feed them a variety of different foods to stop them from being bored of the same food.

Comment: Its seems that the slow sinking pellets work ok except they don't really eat very much before it his the bottom and don't seem to be interested in it once its there. They mysis works best, although the guy at petco said they should only be fed it about twice weekly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty simple:  Turn off the filters/water flowing for a short period of time.